# Custom ROM on a stock S5 with custom kernel?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-5, kernel

A couple months back, I have installed a custom kernel on my Samsung S5 with stock Touchwiz. Now I want to flash a custom ROM on this phone and was wondering if I can do it while my kernel is not the one associated to the running stock ROM on my phone? Is it safe to do so or do I have to revert back to stock kernel before doing so?